# How to find the start position and end position in a Length of longest subarray balanced problem

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, divide-and-conquer

Given some curly braces, both opening and closing curly braces. Find the length of the longest subarray that is balanced. Also, find which position the longes subarray

that is balanced starts and at which it ends. In case of multiple subarrays have the same length, consider the first one.

Input

`5`

`{}{}{`

Output

`4`

`1 4`

Explanation

{}{} is balanced and the length is 4. It starts from position 1 and ends at position 4(1 based indexing)

I have got the length but I am not able to get the first position and last position. Can someone please tell how to tweak the function to get the first position and last position?

```
int findMaxLen(string str) 
{ 
    int n = str.length(); 
    stack<int> stk; 
    stk.push(-1); 

    int result = 0; 

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
    { 
        if (str[i] == '{') 
          stk.push(i); 

        else 
        { 
            stk.pop(); 

            if (!stk.empty()) 
                result = max(result, i - stk.top()); 
            else stk.push(i); 
        } 
    } 

    return result; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone please tell how to tweak the function to get the first position and last position?

You are tracking only the length of the maximum-so-far balanced substring.  You need to also track either its start or end index, so instead of

> ```
>                 result = max(result, i - stk.top());
> ```

use an `if` block with the corresponding condition:

```
                  if (result < i - stk.top()) {
                      // ...
                  }
```

.  In that block's body, update both `result` and the corresponding end or start index.  When you're done, the combination of length and one index gives you the other index.  Details are left as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: *Can someone please tell how to tweak the function to get the first position and last position?*

You can use my implementation below to find start and end indices:

```
def findMaxLen(string): 
    n = len(string) 

    # Create a stack and push -1 as initial index to it. 
    stk = [] 
    stk.append(-1) 

    # Initialize result 
    result = 0
    tracker = []

    # Traverse all characters of given string 
    for i in range(n): 

        # If opening bracket, push index of it 
        if string[i] == '{': 
            stk.append(i) 

        else:    # If closing bracket, i.e., str[i] = '}' 

            # Pop the previous opening bracket's index 
            stk.pop() 

            # Check if this length formed with base of 
            # current valid substring is more than max  
            # so far 
            if len(stk) != 0: 
                if result < i - stk[len(stk)-1]:
                    result = i - stk[len(stk)-1]
                    tracker.append((result,i))

            # If stack is empty. push current index as  
            # base for next valid substring (if any) 
            else: 
                stk.append(i) 

    return result,tracker

#string = "{{{}"
#string = "}{}{}}"
string = "{}{{}}}}}"
result,tracker = findMaxLen(string)
for t in tracker:
    if t[0] == result:
        end_index = t[1]

# length of longest substring (balanced)
print (result)

# print (start and end locations of that substring)
print (" ".join([str(end_index - result + 2),str(end_index + 1)]))
```